# How often should a dog pee and poop normally?

Tags: dogs, health, defecation, urination

Some articles I have found say it's 3-5 times a day, some say 2-3 times a day with no more than 8-12 hours between times when dog gets out.

My mother's dog (English Springer Spaniel) is used to being taken out 2 times a day. 7-8 in the morning and ~11 in the evening. He only poops in the morning. He seems to be used to this schedule, he does not seem too needy in morning and evening.

I guess my question is, is twice a day not enough and is this hurting the dog in the long run?

Or should I convince my mother that 3 times are needed?

Comment: I think this could potentially cause the dog to have a urinary tract infection or kidney stones from holding it so long. Most of the trainers on the positive reinforcement groups I am on say that four hours is about as long as you should expect a dog to hold it, even an adult dog. OTOH I've had jobs where I had to be out of the house for 14 or more hours with no known health consequences to the dog.

Comment: This could be a problem later on but it shouldn't be too serious. I would agree that dogs normally "do their business" more frequently.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it will depend"... on what the dog is fed (how much, how often and at what time of the day) and on exercise (how much, how often, and what type the dog is given) and on the dog (both age and health will play a part). It just isn't one thing, but many things to evaluate and take into consideration.
I have a Basenji. Her winter schedule includes ~1 hour of playtime at the dog park, where she can wrestle with the other pups and run full tilt in games of tag, and at least one other outing. She does well with this routine. Most of her toiletting is done at the dog park (activity naturally expedites this). She does well with this and sometimes has to remind me that it's time to go play.
The schedule your Mother has for her ESS should be fine. It is considered a typical day for thousands of loved pups. I'm certain that your Mother's dog has a way to communicate if she needs an extra trip outside. An ESS is a high energy dog, so it would be ideal if their walks were around 30 minutes each, but two "outings" a day shouldn't create any health problems.